# Slide toggle nav only works on home page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, nav

Site in question: http://mtthwbsh.com

For my mobile nav I am using the following script to toggle it open/closed:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
/* toggle nav */
$("#menu-icon").on("click", function(){
    $(".nav").slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $("#menu-icon img").toggleClass("rotate");
});
});
```

This works fine on the homepage, but on interior pages it does not toggle, and when searching and viewing the results the entire nav disappears. I am using a conditional tag to load a separate nav on interior pages and am not sure if this is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your smoothscroll.js throws an error, which probably stops the rest of your javascript from being executed:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
```

that happens when it is searching for an id "#work" which seems to be missing

Comment: I saw that error but thought it was unrelated, I can't seem to find where it is looking for "#work"?

Comment: smoothscroll loops over anchor-links, and in your case the anchor with the id "work" is missing, so smoothscroll doesnt know where to scroll to and throws that error

Comment: I actually used another conditional tag to not load smoothscroll.js anywhere but the homepage, since this is the only place I use it. Not sure if this is the best fix for now, but it appears to be toggling. Thanks!

Comment: Still not sure about the mobile nav completely disappearing on the search results page, but I'll credit you for this answer.